# Running gimp plugins from shell on mac

Tags: python, macos, shell, gimp

I am facing some problem while trying to execute a batch plugin for gimp from shell on mac. I am using gimp 2.8.

The problem is that if i run gimp from shell, using : `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp '(python-fu-test-hello-world)'`

It will show some mesages, then `batch command executed successfully`

But actually nothing will happen, the code inside the python script will not run. Any special considerations needed?

Can someone shed some lights on what is going on ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you make the script executable with `chmod +x scriptName.py`?

Comment: The command you have given is not how you run script commands from the command line. Where is your -b switch?

Comment: I am using the script at [link](http://gimpbook.com/scripting/gimp-script-templates/helloworld.py)
I made the script executable and am running now with : `/Applications/GIMP.app/Contents/MacOS/gimp -b '(python-fu-hello-world "Hello World !" "Sans" 50 (1.0 0.0 0.0))'`
I am getting an error : 
`batch command experienced an execution error:
Error: ( : 2) illegal function `